# jQuery Cookie needs to have unique name

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a number of pages coming from WordPress that at any one time can have an alert div at the top of the page containing different info. I'm setting a cookie via a button which also dismisses the alert. As the jQuery is held in one place it's always going to set the same cookie for all pages and therefore not show the alert on any other page.

Any ideas how to make the cookie unique page by page, i.e. maybe take the page title and use that as the name? Is there a better way of doing this? Any advice would be appreciated. I'm using js-cookie library.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cookie Test</title>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>
    function setCookie(){   
    Cookies.set("csalert", "true",  { expires: 1});
    };
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //the dismiss button triggers the function setCookie and hides the alert container
    $("#dismiss").click(function(){
        $(".alert-container").hide();
    });

    //if the cookie is set then do not show the alert or dismiss button on next page load
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('csalert') >= 0) {
        $('.alert-container').hide();
    }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="alert-container">
  <div class="alert-message-container">This is our alert message.</div>
    <a href="#" id="dismiss" onclick="setCookie()">Dismiss</a>
  </div>
<h1 class="entry-title">Page title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you able to generate a random long string of characters as the cookie value and reference them to the stuff that contains those info

Comment: No because it would be random every-time and when it hit the last if statement it would have to start all over again setting a different cookie name and the banner would show. I think I might use the end of the page url, i.e. /about-us

Comment: But that’s provided if u only need to set cookie for a small amount of stuff

Comment: But how would a random number help me get a unique name for the cookie for any particular page?

Comment: You could appned those cookie to JSON that references to the page i think